# How to keep hover effect only on the parent

Tags: css

I'm developing a css Tree view and I want, if is possible, to keep the hover effect only on the element that has children:

```
    <ul>
      <li><span>Item 1</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Item 1.1</span></li>
          <li><span>Item 1.2</span></li>
          <li><span>Item 1.3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

What I've done in css was:

```
.treeview li>ul>span:hover, .treeview li>ul>span:hover+ul li span {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #94a0b4;
    color:#000
}
```

but this doesn't work like I expected.

Comment: Exactly what elements are you trying to apply the hover too? just the Item 1 span?

Comment: The `ul` is a child of the `li` not the `span`.

Comment: @Kierchon in this case, only the item 1. But also if the item 1.1 has a child (Item 1.1.1) I want also the item 1.1 to be highlighted

Comment: You can't evaluate if some element has childrens or not with CSS maybe with Jquery, can i give you an option with Jquery? Or you can add an specific class to those items that have childrens and you want to be highlighted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the :hover effect only inside the "Item 1" right?

```
.treeview > ul > li:hover > span {
    color: red;
}
```

Also check [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLaJk/).

UPDATED (based on your comment)

```
.treeview  li:hover > span {
    color: red;
}
```

And [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLaJk/1/). This however will also trigger the span on "Item 1.1.1" when hovered...

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Defoncesko/p63b9/

HTML

```
<div class="treeview">
        <ul>
          <li><span>Item 1</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>Item 1.1</span></li>
              <li><span>Item 1.2</span></li>
              <li><span>Item 1.3</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  ul ul li:hover {
        background-color:#eee;
        border:1px solid #94a0b4;
        color:#000
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I added another larger li in my fiddle so you can see.

```
.treeview ul>li>span:hover {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #94a0b4;
    color:#000
}
.treeview ul>li>span ~ ul>li>span:hover {
    background:#fff;
    border:none;
    color:#000
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/QdEEf/1/

Edit: Actually If im truly understanding your question. Youre looking for a way to determine if the `li` has a `ul` as a child then give that `li` a hover if it does. If this is the case youre gonna need to use javascript to determine if it has a `ul` child. There is no way to do this with CSS